# Метод execute API ВК (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Подскажите пожалуйста на примере как правильно использовать (вызывать) метод execute из API ВК (Node.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо написать сам `vk-script`, затем данный скрипт передаёте в параметре `code` метода `execute`.
Например получение репостов из 25 постов:

```
var data = []; // массив ваших данных
var script = " 
   var posts = [];
   var count = 0;

   while(count<"+data.lenght) {
      var info = API.wall.getReposts({'owner_id':"+data[count][0]+", 'post_id':"+data[count][1]+"});
      posts.push(info.profiles);
      count = count+1;
    }

return posts; 
";

var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'https://api.vk.com/method',
  port: 80,
  path: '/execute?code='+script
};

http.get(options, function(response){
  response.on('data', function(chunk){
    //обработка ответа
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
  //обработка ошибки
});
```